# How to get in-place archive custom folder name on office 365?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, ews-managed-api

`GET mailFolders/archivemsgfolderroot`

I use distinguish name to get this in-place mailbox folder
and the response is:

```
...
"displayName": "Top of Information Store",
...
```

However, this is not the custom name I modified on office365.
Is it possible to get that custom name?

I also try to get distinguish folder in EWS managed API

`<t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="archivemsgfolderroot" />`

It returns the same name

```
...
<t:DisplayName>Top of Information Store</t:DisplayName>
...
```

--

Add two image ref.

[how I add it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqHbV.png)

[how it looks like at outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yeiD.png)

thanks for help

Comment: How did you set the "custom name"?

Comment: @RichardFuller , I set the custom name at (Admin Center -> Exchange Admin Center -> mailboxes -> any user -> In-Place Archive -> View details

Comment: "Top of Information Store" is the root folder of all viewable items in an Exchange mailbox.  "msgfolderroot" is for the user's primary mailbox and "archivemsgfolderroot" is for the user's archive mailbox.

I'm not sure if changing its name is possible as it is a special folder.  Can you take a screenshot of what the setting looks like?  Maybe it's doing something different.

Comment: @RichardFuller, updated the post, thank you for paying attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that a user can set a property, "ArchiveName", to give their archive mailbox a custom name. In powershell, this would be using a Set-Mailbox cmdlet.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/set-mailbox?view=exchange-ps

That doc states that it applies to Outlook and OWA and, after a quick look, I can't see a way to get that property other than using Get-Mailbox which is not ideal.  So as best I can tell it's not exposed through EWS or REST and thus probably isn't available through Microsoft Graph.

I would encourage you to file a suggestion: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis

Comment: Thank you for answer, I found a solution to get archive name in power shell:
`Get-Mailbox user_name | fl *archivename*`
and I am still searching for a EWS and REST way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following endpoint
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/archivemsgfolderroot/childFolders/AAMkADQ5OWMzMGEwLTg4ZjktNDk1Ny05NzFmLWRhZjg4ODU0YzUwYwAuAAAAAACtqDzk9UzLSpZsdesjndr1AQBNzq1HG8BvRYqBQbPeZSPaAAGdwZCCAAA=

（Replace the id to yours）：https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/archivemsgfolderroot/childFolders/id

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I want the name of archivemsgfolderroot itself, not his childFolders

Comment: Although no official document point it but it seems that the DisplayName of the root folder is fixed.What i think is that the archivemsgfolderroot is root(parent) folder of the mailbox,in-place archive custom folder just is the sub-folder of the root folder. So all changes of the in-place archive custom folder should not  affect the DisplayName of the root(parent) folder.              
 If you try again, you can see the "Joe Wu123" folder should been in the child folder(I have double confirm on my side).

Comment: So if you want to get in-place archive custom folder name on office 365, the only choice for you is to use the childFolders and filter the folder.

Comment: Thanks for reply again, it works fine to get children folder's custom name. But what  puzzles me is the fixed name "Top of Information Store" of archive root folder, it could be changed (ref to my post).

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the in-place archive folder. The folder name you changed is just a sub-folder but not the root folder itself. I guess we do not have permission to change the name for the root folder, of course, we cannot find a official document declare this conjecture now.

Comment: Please reference to Richard Fuller's solution below, thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Power Shell, and the above solution does not completely validate. So my reservations.